# VBA - running an excel macro take forever

Tags: excel, vba

I am running this macro and its either taking forever or something is wrong with the way I wrote it. I am new to `Excel Macros`, and I can't seem to figure out how to write this better that it won't crash my PC.

```vb
Sub Test()
    ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim maxRows As Integer
    maxRows = 2332

    For i = maxRows To 2 Step -1
        'if the cell is empty, delete the row
        'otherwise delete the first cell of the row and shift over
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Delete
        End If
    Next i

    ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see the logic behind the ScreenUpdating first being true and then being made false. Are you sure you don't want that reversed? Other than that I don't see any issue, you could maybe also want to check for IsEmpty(Cells(i,2)) but I wouldn't imagine that is causing your issue. You should also try to work with a WorkSheet object instead of using the generic Cells and Rows objects. And try to use Long as a variable instead of Integer but again that is not related to this issue.

Comment: So you mean use `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)` instead?

Comment: Yes you could do that, but its better to avoid ActiveSheet because in the future you may use a macro from outside of a sheet, so as good practice, Dim a new Worksheet object and work using that. Dim mySheet as Worksheet. Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetNameAsString"). And later use the Rows and Cells objects of that sheet such as: mySheet.Cells(i,2) or mySheet.Rows(i).Delete.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I manage to reduce the run-time from `10+ seconds and possible crashes` to `3-4 seconds`. I have a web application background and we say anything take `1 second` or longer is too slow. But here I think I can live with `3 seconds`.

Comment: Did you also look into the Application.ScreenUpdating? I believe you wanted to set that to False at first and then to True after you are done. It might further speed it up if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: The only reason why I want to use `ActiveSheet` instead, is because I do not know what the sheet name will be. I am writing this for a friend, and I will export and send the macro to her. `Application.ScreenUpdating` is actually made a significant difference. I did not understand its `Boolean` at first, and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Are you using truly empty cells? Or are they the result of formula outcome being ""? Because with truly empty cells you can do that in one go without any loop at all.

Answer (score 2):

In general, whenever `delete` is used, it is a good idea to do it only once, for all the cases. However, in the case of the OP, there are two cases separately - deleting a whole row and deleting only one cell. Thus, the `delete` method could be used twice:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim maxRows As Long: maxRows = 2332
    Dim myRangeRows As Range
    Dim myRangeCells As Range

    Dim i As Long
    For i = maxRows To 2 Step -1
        With Worksheets(1)
            If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
                If myRangeRows Is Nothing Then
                    Set myRangeRows = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set myRangeRows = Union(.Rows(i), myRangeRows)
                End If
            Else
                If myRangeCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set myRangeCells = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set myRangeCells = Union(.Cells(i, 1), myRangeCells)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    If Not myRangeRows Is Nothing Then myRangeRows.Delete
    If Not myRangeCells Is Nothing Then myRangeCells.Delete

End Sub
```

Additionally, whenever the cell in Excel is referred like this `Cells(i, 2).Value`, then the referring is either to the `ActiveSheet` or to the Worksheet in which the code resides. Thus, it is a good practice to explicitly mention the worksheet, like in this case:

```
With Worksheets(1)
    If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
```

Comment: What do you think was causing his error thou? I believe it was not using a sheet object before referring to the Cells and Rows objects. I haven't tested it however. Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: @Lorne - no idea. The assumption is probably a good one, but there could be many other reasons, e.g. there is a `Worksheet_Change` event that "plays" somehow against the deleted code and somehow runs another procedure, that takes a lot of time.

Comment: Reading your edit once again, I think the answer to my question is "no". Deleting generic Rows or Cells object wouldn't cause a problem as long as he is on the active sheet, my reasoning was way wrong. Thanks thou, I am a bit new and still learning.